# XAMPP acceder a dominio virtual desde el móvil

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

Tengo creado un servidor virtual en Windows con XAMPP, al cual desde la PC accedo sin problemas. Suponiendo que mi IP Estática de mi PC es 192.168.1.10 y mi dominio virtual definido en mi PC es ventas.sysmec.net... cómo accedo a ese dominio desde el móvil?

Desde mi PC puedo acceder directamente a mi web app a través del dominio virtual (escribiendo ventas.sysmec.net) o con la ip (192.168.1.10), sin embargo, en el móvil no logro ingresar a la misma a través del dominio virtual.

Sí puedo acceder desde la IP definida (Es decir, al ingresar 192.168.1.10 en el móvil ingresa a la web app), pero esto supone un problema debido a que trabajo con un app con CodeIgniter, y en el mismo, he configurado que el directorio principal sea el dominio virtual (es decir, ventas.sysmec.net), generando esto un error en el acceso desde el móvil, ya que al ser inaccesible el dominio virtual, no logra descargar los archivos CSS, js y demás, necesarios para la correcta ejecución del la plataforma.

**EDITO:**
El móvil SÍ está dentro de la misma red WiFi. Por eso, originalmente aclaré que desde el móvil SÍ se puede acceder al servidor mediante la IP. Lo que yo deseo es que desde el móvil se pueda acceder al servidor mediante el mismo dominio virtual creado a través del archivo hosts de Windows.

Comment: Si el móvil está en la red celular, va a viajar afuera de tu red local y nadie aparte de tu dominio virtual sabe a dónde enrutar ventas.sysmec.net, comenzando por tu proveedor de datos móviles. La respuesta que te dan atiende esa necesidad: deben estar en la misma red local

Comment: Cuando entras por medio de la ip lo hace directo y sin problemas, en la pc tienes tu archivo host con ese dominio, en cambio en el movil no. Por eso puedes ingresar por medio de ip pero no de dominio.

Comment: Exactamente Eduardo, eso es lo que pasa. Entonces... no hay forma de que el dominio sea reconocido por el móvil sin usar dominios magicos y similares?

Comment: Ningún servidor DNS en el mundo sabe cómo traducir ventas.sysmec.net. Sólo lo sabe tu dominio virtual local.

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo por tu predisposición. Quiero comentarte que yo NO estoy hablando de una ip pública. Es una red LOCAL con WiFi. Dentro de esta red, si ingreso la dirección ventas.sysmec.net en la PC ingresa a la web app, sin problemas. Si ingreso la misma dirección en el móvil, no funciona. Sin embargo, si tanto en el móvil como en la PC ingreso la IP de la PC que posee los archivos de la web app, en ambos casos ingresa sin problemas. Lo que quiero es que en el móvil también pueda ingresar a la web app a través del dominio y no por la IP.

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada si quieres acceder desde tu movil (u otro dispositivo) distinto a tu "servidor local" (en este caso tu notebook o pc) deben estar conectados a la misma red wifi o en su defecto desde tu celular compartir wifi a tu notebook (no es necesario tener acceso a internet desde tu movil) con esto estas creando una red de area local,

para poder acceder desde tu movil a la ip de tu pc donde tengas configurado tu proyecto debes usar lo que se llaman dominios magico la que yo uso y recomiendo (me parece que es la mas conocida) se llama xip.io esta te provee un dns para acceder desde otro equipo que no sea el servidor 
 Aunque ese dominio no exista realmente, xip.io lo hará corresponder con la IP adecuada.

El trabajo es bien simple. Imagina que la IP de tu ordenador de desarrollo es 192.168.0.242, pues entonces podrás escribir:

http://192.168.0.242.xip.io y el sistema de DNS lo hará corresponder con la IP 192.168.0.242

puede configurarlo con virtualhost igualmente, espero te sirva y te de una luz de como continuar